# How to read data from a json file using node.js

Tags: node.js, json

I need to read my user Id to know what the timestart number is but I don't find the way to read the data.

```
//My code
const fs = require('fs');
var timePath = 'test.json'
var TimeRead = fs.readFileSync(timePath);
var timeFile = JSON.parse(TimeRead); //ready for use
var userId = "2"

var Time = TimeRead.userId.TimeStart; 

console.log(Time)
```

> 1 is my user Id variable

```
//My json File
{
  "1": {
    "TimeStart": 1626909816680
  },
  "2": {
    "TimeStart": 1627166305644
  }
}
```

Comment: Please say what the problem is. If the code you posted does not work, show the error or explain what is wrong.

Comment: your ignoring timeFile after decode, use that instead, `timeFile[userId].TimeStart`

Comment: Test question: Why do you assume that in `TimeRead.userId.TimeStart` the `userId` refers to `2` while assuming at the same time that `TimeStart` refers to `"TimeStart"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Time = TimeRead.userId.TimeStart;
```

You can't use a variable with `.`

Try this:

```
var Time = TimeRead[userId].TimeStart;
```